# What is this quarter window part called, and how can I get a replacement?

Tags: chrysler, window, sebring

I am in the process of swapping out the rear driver side quarter window regulator on my 2003 Chrysler Sebring Convertible. I've removed the glass and the regulator. I've purchased the new regulator and am ready to put it in. However, I just realized I am somehow missing one of the little plastic **threaded** washers that goes against the glass. It looks like this:

[image: Little plastic washer that goes against the glass window]
[image: Picture found online showing the glass window with washers]

Where can I get a replacement? I don't even know what the part is actually called in order to buy one online if needed.

**UPDATE**

It appears to be called a "glass to lift plate bushing", it's a 2-part bushing. I do have the other part. Looks like a black plastic t-nut that screws into the middle of this white plastic piece. Then the screw from the window regulator screws into the black t-nut to hold everything together.

I did find this: [Factory Chrysler Parts](http://www.factorychryslerparts.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=571830&ukey_model=15475&ukey_modelrange=0&ukey_make=1061) and I think it might be piece 12 or 13, but I can't tell for sure. Don't really want to pay for the part and $10 for shipping just for it to be the wrong piece.

**UPDATE 2**

As mentioned in the comment below. I will provide an answer to my question once the parts come in, and I verify exactly what it is. (Assuming I ordered the correct part)

Comment: I went ahead and ordered both 12 and 13 from that site. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: Rather than update the question with an answer, please use the Answer area below to add the solution. Yes, it is ok to answer your own question. This will indicate in the question list that there is an answer.

Comment: Right. I wasn't 100% sure if my answer, and was hoping to hear from someone more knowledgable on the subject. I ordered the parts I mentioned above. Once they arrive, and I can verify that it is indeed what I said in my "update". Then I'll provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my update to my question, I'm fairly certain it is a "glass to lift plate bushing", it's a 2-part bushing. Looks like a black plastic t-nut that screws into the middle of this white plastic piece. Then the screw from the window regulator screws into the black t-nut to hold everything together.

I mentioned I was going to purchase one from Factory Chrysler Parts, but I have cancelled that order. So I won't be able to find out exactly the name from that order.

Instead, I found 2 nylon washers of about the same size, that when placed together have about the same thickness. I have placed this against the window and put everything back together. Everything seems to be working great.